# How to convert a list of strings with space delimited floats to a dataframe

Tags: python, list

I have list of element as below:

```
['1.3 2.4 3.6','4.6 5 6.8','6.5 7.2 8.1']
```

where each element has few observations separated by space.

I want to convert this to dataframe. I am stuck, how to separate each observation and form dataframe?

Comment: What will be the shape of this dataframe? Each string is a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with:

- `split` function to separate string
- `float` function to convert str to float
- list comprehension

A one line instruction can do what you want

```
data = ['1.3 2.4 3.6','4.6 5 6.8','6.5 7.2 8.1']
dataframe = [[float(x) for x in e.split()] for e in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must Iterate over the elements of the list (the strings). For each of these strings you use the split operator. At the end of this process you will have a list of lists. So, you just create the dataframe by passing that list of lists. The code below illustrates what I just said.

```
import pandas as pd

l = ['1.3 2.4 3.6','4.6 5 6.8','6.5 7.2 8.1']

columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

data = [[float(x) for x in e.split()] for e in l]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

lst = ['1.3 2.4 3.6','4.6 5 6.8','6.5 7.2 8.1']

d = [[float(l) for l in i.split()] for i in lst]

col = 'a b c'.split()

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d, columns= col )
print(df)
```

`split()` splits a string into a list , by default the delimiter is white space

`d = [[float(l) for l in i.split()] for i in lst]`

here you are using a list comprehension, where you  iterate through each element in `lst` and splitting the string

`'1.3 2.4 3.6'` into a list `[1.3, 2.4, 3.6]` and using `float(l)` to type cast it to float

Output:

```
     a    b    c
0  1.3  2.4  3.6
1  4.6  5.0  6.8
2  6.5  7.2  8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to separate each of the element of list and then you can again split them and convert into float

```
data = ['1.3 2.4 3.6','4.6 5 6.8','6.5 7.2 8.1']
result = []
for row in data:
    value_list = row.split(' ') 
    result += value_list

result = list(map(float, result))

print(result)
```

Above given code still can be optimized using pythonic ways but it is deliberately kept simpler for you to understand the flow.